# Performance Benchmarking Doctrine 2

Tags: performance, zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I recently tried to benchmark my Zend App with Doctrine 2 using Zend CE simple benchmark tool. In the Zend App's index controller's index action, I added simple functionality to create a User entity, persist the entity, and flush the entity manager.

I noticed that the persist and flush operations alone dropped my Zend App's RPS from 50 to 11. Then I realized that maybe adding metadata cache would improve performance. Turns out adding ApcCache driver and setting it to metadata cache only improves the RPS to 16.

Are there any suggestions as to how I can improve the performance of persist and flush methods? Or is it time for me to bail Doctrine 2 and move to the simpler Zend Database framework?

Comment: Maybe sharing your setup would be more useful. You could help us getting better performance in `DoctrineModule` itself. Flushing entities usually takes a long time with large units of work. Consider clearing your unit of work if you work with 100+ records.